# Two objects vs. Object+Prepositional phrase and "request you to" vs. "request that"

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-pattern

> **We request you to kindly send us the feedback**

**Two objects:** The verb "send" in it has two objects, "us" - Indirect object" & "the feedback" - Direct object

> **We request you to kindly send the feedback to us**

**Object + Prepositional phrase:** The verb "send" in it has "the feedback" - Direct object and "to us" - Prepositional phrase

I think both sentences are correct and interchangeable.

I learned that the choice of sentence pattern depends on the point of interest. My point of interest here in the above example is "the feedback", so it should come at the end of the sentence i.e, the first example is correct - **"We request you to kindly send us the feedback"**

However, the second example **"We request you to kindly send the feedback to us"** seems to be more formal than the first one.

So I want to know which one is more formal and common in use.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**Question update:**

I asked the above question for a different reason and now I'm stuck in another different subject. I have searched a lot in Google and got results that **"request you to"** is wrong and we should always use **"request that"**. Also got results that **"you to send"** is correct but not **"you to kindly send"** because of split infinitives.

But we Indians always use **"request you to kindly"**. So please clarify that is it acceptable to use as a grammar method we can follow in Indian English or we are still using it wrong and need to change it.

If we need to change our writing method, is the below example correct?

> **"We request that you kindly send us the feedback"**

Also I have one more doubt that,

> **"We kindly request that you send us the feedback"**
>   has different meaning than 
>   **"We request that you kindly send us the feedback"**

Because, one doesn't need to be kind enough to request but the other person is the one who we request to be kind to give us feedback. Right?

Please help me understand the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any semantic difference depends on context.  Both can be equally "formal", again depending on context.  Both are relatively common.  This is more a question of writing style -- sometimes one "sounds" better than the other.

Comment: [You don't have "one more doubt"; you have "one more question".](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/294125/2085). Mis-using *doubt* to mean *question* is another of those notorious English mistakes that makes native speakers shake their heads. It's always a mistranslation from some foreign language's pattern into English. You should also say "the following example" or "this example" not "the below example": there's no such thing as "a below" in English, for *below* is an adverb not an adjective, and cannot be nominalized.

Comment: @tchrist Correct me if I'm wrong about anything. I will definitely correct it next time. I always want to learn from linguists like you. English is my second language. So I make mistakes and I'm learning everyday. However, I can show you examples for "below example" and "one more doubt" which is widely accepted and used.

Comment: These glitches are all ones that second-language learners of English commonly pick up (especially but not uniquely those living in the Indian Subcontinent) that come off as sounding “funny/weird/off/wrong” to native speakers in the US and the UK. We should help you guys out by finding some Internet resource that summarizes these if you'd like to be aware of ways that Indian English differs from various other forms of English. It might be thought of as being a colorful local dialect/accent, but you may sometimes wish to avoid risking making a bad impression outside of your region.

Comment: I recommend our resident (now-retired) English professor John Lawler's [long posting on Indian English](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/indian.html) as a good start. You can then move on to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) and other resources.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for your explanation. But "Please find below detail" is widely used. If it's wrong, then how should I tell this?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/611 and https://english.stackexchange.com/a/354887 for specific examples and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/above-below?mixed=1 in general.

Comment: @tchrist https://english.stackexchange.com/a/613/213946 this answer says **"the below information"** is correct

Comment: It does say that, but you also need to understand why it is so widely held to be otherwise. Many native speakers reject it as grammatical; others consider it to be in a super-formal legalistic-style register. In America it may be more widely frowned upon than widely used.

Comment: Since I want to improve my English, I will definitely follow your advice. But I have one question (doubt), if I say **"Please find the information below"**, Is that "**the** information" correct? Because we use **"the"** here mostly to mention something that was already mentioned or known, right?

Comment: @Raj33 *The* is fine there; the speaker believes the listener will be able to identify what specifically *information* refers to.  But this would be better if you posted it as a separate question instead of in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is right.  You do not "request...to...".  You "request that...".

Your two examples also have different meanings.  The first one indicates that the user will be kind in sending feedback.  The second says that you are asking kindly (meaning politely) for feedback.

You can instead say

> We kindly request that you send us feedback.

Which is the most natural and formal rewriting.  If there is a previously mentioned feedback that we are referring to, we can say

> We kindly request that you send the feedback to us.

If you are intent on using "to," then you can use it with "ask."

> We kindly ask you to send us feedback

But it's strange to use "kindly" with the less formal "ask."

================ Edit: additional info about kindly ===============

**Kindly** is a little bit of an archaic word in both the context of kindly asking someone to do something and asking someone to kindly do something.

Kindly asking someone to do something is used frequently in written English, especially formal English.  It just means you are asking them politely.  Here the archaic nature of the usage lends the word its formality.  "We kindly ask that you..." is used in a lot of official or formal correspondence when the speaker is emphasizing that they do not wish to bully you.

Asking someone to kindly do something is less common but could also appear in written, formal language or in sarcastic language.  Asking someone to kindly do something is frequently used in old movies and books by a stuffy schoolmarm asking children to kindly pay attention or kindly sit up straight.  I would suggest that you avoid it unless you are speaking to people who are not native English speakers and therefore think it is common and polite usage.

The statement by both you and the writer of the page that you reference indicating that you do not need to be kind to ask is based on faulty logic.  When you "kindly ask" it means "politely ask," so don't base your choice on the literal meaning of the word in isolation.  Does the person have to do what you are requesting kindly?  No, they don't.  They may respond rudely--it's their choice and if you are polite you will accept either a rude or a kind response.  By instructing them to do something kindly you are talking down to them in a way that is not frequently done in modern English.

I notice that the link you sent seems to be written by Indians about Indian English.  Because India is a nation that speaks English as a second language, Indian English has a lot of quirks that the rest of the English-speaking world would consider incorrect.  If you plan to speak exclusively with people from India/Pakistan, then you may want to use what is accepted there, regardless of whether a native English speaker would say it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been using "request you to" for years and also seen others using the same. I have one doubt in your answer, you said "Your two examples also have different meanings. The first one indicates that the user will be kind in sending feedback. The second says that you are asking kindly (meaning politely) for feedback." My question is, which one is appropriate here? I should be kindly ask or I ask the other one to be kindly help? Because in some cases, we ask others eg. "Kindly do the needful".

Comment: One doesn't need to be kind enough to request. It is the other person who we ask to be kind to give us the feedback. Right?

Comment: No. I'd say the normal thing to say is that we kindly request. You don't want to sound like you are ordering people to do something. Using kindly to describe someone else's actions is sometimes an idiomatic way to order them to do something. "You will kindly hold your tongue!"

Comment: have a look at this page https://m.rediff.com/getahead/2007/may/28eng.htm they say "kindly request" is wrong

Comment: Also have a look at this page https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-would-request-vs-i-request-vs-i-would-like-to-request.3244689/ one person said that it could be British English. Please clarify this. Because I have seen a lot of business mails received from throughout India. All of them use "request you to kindly".

Comment: The first page is wrong. Their "correct" examples are very wrong.  I'd stick with advice from native speakers if I were you.

Comment: India learned a poor version of English while under British rule and many usages that are wrong are now commonplace in India.  If you are dealing with Indians, then perhaps making the same error would be fine, but if you ever deal with Americans, British, Australians, or other real native speakers, avoid "request you to" as it is wrong.  The placement of kindly is grammatically correct in either location.  I have given you my opinion on where it is more common.  Avoid the rediff page, as the writer appears to have poor understanding of English.

Comment: I agree with the answer "request that" is correct. And also I agree "we kindly request" is more natural and common usage. However, the other explanation about the placement of "kindly" seems to be right to me that we are requesting that the other person to be kindly send the feedback. We are not ordering here because we already mentioned the word "request" in the start of the sentence. So it seems right to me.

Comment: I have added some info about this to my answer.  Using "kindly" that way is not grammatically wrong, it's just not common and it can be rude.  You are telling people to be kind and that's presumptuous.  Telling someone to do something kindly can easily be seen as sarcastic.  You are welcome to get a second opinion, but I suggest you get it from a native speaker, whether American (like me) or British.

Comment: Also I would like to say that this comment is little rude - "India learned a poor version of English while under British rule and many usages that are wrong are now commonplace in India" Please try some other way to make these kind of sentences whenever you talk to other natives.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answers. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70624/discussion-between-farnsy-and-raj-33).

Comment: @Raj33 These sociolinguistic attitudes are unfortunate but common. Indian English is difficult to fit into some descriptive frameworks that privilege the native speaker above all else because it is spoken almost exclusively by non-native speakers, so people deny its validity as a language variety.  And yet, many characteristics of IndE are well-established and undeniably *not* mistakes, for example new lexemes like *prepone*. They only become errors when used in other varieties of English like American or British English where they are non-standard; in India there is nothing wrong with them.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I would like to let others know that we Indians are not using something totally strange or funny or poor English here. The question I asked here "request you to" was once a widely used practice in your language too. But we are still using it. That's the only difference I see here. So, if something is not used or outdated in your region, then you should answer that "this is how we say it in USA now" rather than "this is totally wrong, you shouldn't use it and it's total strange and funny to hear". These kind of answers always confuses non-native English speakers

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit surprised at some people's attitudes toward English usage outside of Br and Am.

Comment: it is not just the UK and US.  Au, nz, Canada, and every other English speaking country agree on this example.  Only India uses request this way.  India is a fine country but so many English speakers there learned it after their first language and/it from folks who don't speak it natively.  I think in this example there is a clear consensus on whether this usage is appropriate today.  It is not.  The dictionary is full of ways to use words that are not appropriate in English speaking 2017.